# Which containers should I use for souffles?

Tags: baking, equipment, eggs, souffle

I want to make some individual zabaglione & fruit souffles, but don't have ramekins. Also, I don't have much experience with souffles (but I have made them some times).

I have at my disposal:

- 10 cm tartalette forms, nonstick, made from some very thin sheet metal, probably steel

  6 cm silicone muffin cups

  6 cm muffin pan paper liners. I have made muffins in them, stacked in twos on a rack. The muffins  flow much wider than when contained in a pan, but are still not too flat.

  plain porcelain tea cups

Which alternative will work best, and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out of each of these I would say the tea cups although I really think you would be better to purchase/borrow a souffle dish. The souffle needs to rise and a vertical makes this far easier.

I wouldn't use anything metal is it may get too hot too quickly and overcook the outside of the souffle.

Something else you might want to try is to use a casserole dish but make sides from heavy duty aluminium foil (about 6 inches high should do) or use a deep baking tin.